# create root@localhost fails in mysql

Tags: mysql

I dont have 'root'@'localhost' in my MySQL instances.
I am trying to create the same but it is giving me below error

> ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'

My netbackup agent requires a 'root'@'localhost' user to run. Eventhough i have 'root'@'127.0.0.1' in my instance, netbackup agent by default uses 'root'@'localhost' and fails with "Access Denied for 'root'@'localhost' error"  I cannot change the behavior of netbackup agent.

I was about to update the mysql.user table

> UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='localhost' WHERE Host='127.0.0.1' AND User='root';

I have two questions

1. Why MySQL is not allowing me to create a user as 'root'@'localhost'
2. Any impact on updating the mysql.user table ? Will it work or corrupt anything

**Edit1:**

Tried all the options suggested already. Reproducing that to show you the output.

I can create 'root'@'%' and 'root'@'127.0.0.1', but MySQL just don't allow me to create 'root'@'localhost' user

```
[mysql@hostnameXX ~]$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.014 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.017 ms


mysql> rename user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' to 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation RENAME USER failed for 'root'@'127.0.0.1'

mysql> rename user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' to 'root'@'localhost';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation RENAME USER failed for 'root'@'127.0.0.1'
mysql> 
mysql> drop user 'root'@'127.0.0.1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user,host from mysql.user where user='root';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create user 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'Password@123';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your OS and your MySQL version?  On your system, does localhost resolve to 127.0.0.1 and does a reverse lookup of 127.0.0.1 give localhost?

Comment: 1. because it already exists, probably as a unix_socket authenticated user. 2. hell and damnation, possible corruption too :-) - use ALTER USER. Don't fiddle with mysql system tables directly.

Comment: 1) Show `SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();` 2) Show `SHOW GRANTS;` 3) *netbackup agent by default uses 'root'@'localhost'* The program cannot specify a hostpart of the username, MySQL detects it. Check does your netbackup uses IPv4 or socks? it seems that the last one - in this case check does socks connections are allowed. 4) *I was about to update the mysql.user table* Do it never! it can have unpredictable effect, up to the system data damage.